# INSERT FROM other table if the record not exists taking long time

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I am doing insert query from one table to another table.
The query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO analytics_user (brokerage_id, email, first_name, last_name, landing_page_source, sign_up_time, user_id) 
  SELECT brokerage_id, email, first_name, last_name, landing_page_source, sign_up_time, user_id 
  FROM user  
  WHERE user_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM analytics_user);
```

I have like 1M record in user table, is there a better way to do it? because it's taking too long time to make it done, like more than 20 mins, or it just freeze and I have to restart the server.

**UPDATE:**

SHOW INDEX FROM analytics_user

```
analytics_user  0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   10687   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
analytics_user  0   brokerage_id    1   brokerage_id    A   10687   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
analytics_user  0   user_id 1   user_id A   10687   NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `user_id` column in `analytics_user` table? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19794735/edit) your question and post the result of `SHOW INDEX FROM analytics_user`.

Comment: Looking at the question, "is there a better way to do this?", how about not doing it?  Why not simply use data from the user table?

Comment: @DanBracuk The difference is just like the table name one is for analytic which added more column to get report of the user, so the analytics_user table is necessary for me.

Comment: Then all you want is the user_id.  You can get stuff like names and email addresses by joining the two tables.

Comment: So what does the execution plan say?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this might it help u

```
INSERT INTO analytics_user
(brokerage_id, email, first_name, last_name, landing_page_source, sign_up_time, user_id) 
(
SELECT 
brokerage_id, email, first_name, last_name, landing_page_source, sign_up_time,
     user_id 
FROM user A 
Left join analytics_user b on A.User_Id=B.User_Id
 where B.User_Id is null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, Amit, but this query still running long time just like original query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slow because of this:

```
WHERE user_id NOT IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM analytics_user);
```

That construct, while very intutive, is always slow.  Something like this is better:

```
WHERE user_id IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM
user
except
SELECT user_id FROM analytics_user);
```

As pointed out it the comments, you did not specify your database engine.  That's important.  Some databases support the key except, which is used here.  Others support the keyword minus.  There may be others that support neither.

Comment: Hi, Dan Bracuk, Thanks for your help, I am using MySQL, and I think it does't support "expect".